# Sending table data from html form to django views

Tags: html, django

I have a html form which has a table with th,td and POST method and action is to a django view. How can I send my td,th values to the django view?

I have tried using input type text and it works but I don't want to use any input type on my td,th rows. Is there a way to access td values directly from django view?

htmlfile:

```
<form method="post" action="display">
{% csrf_token %}
<table name="resultsTable">
<th name="tableHeader">Name</th>
<td name="tableValue">Jon</td>
<button type="Submit">Display</button>
</table>
<form>
```

views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def display(request):
   if request.method=='POST':
      print(request.POST)
```

I want name,jon to be printed in display function

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="display">
{% csrf_token %}
<table name="resultsTable">
<th name="tableHeader"><input type='text' value='Name' name='title_field_name' /></th>
<td name="tableValue"><input type='text' value='Jon' name='data_field_name' />Jon</td>
<button type="Submit">Display</button>
</table>
<form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have already tried this approach and I was hoping to do it without including any inputs in the td and th rows

Comment: I think to do that you would need to send the information back via ajax rather than a Django form.  You would display your rows something like `<th id="tableHeader" data-value="Name">Name</th>` and then within JavaScript set the data you pass back based on the data-value's within the tags.

Answer (score 0):

**htmlfile:**

```html
<form method="post" action="display">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table name="resultsTable">
        <th name="tableHeader">Name</th>
        <td id="name" name="name">{{ form.name }}</td> # form.[name of your model or form atribute]
        <button type="Submit">Display</button>
    </table>
<form>
```

**views.py:**

```py
@csrf_exempt
def display(request):
template_name = 'people_list.html'
   form = YourForm()

   if request.method=='GET':
      context= {"form": form}
      return render(request, self.template_name, context)

   if request.method=='POST':
      form = YourForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          context = {"form": form}
          return render(request, self.template_name, context)
      print(request.POST)
```